# laravel email locale dynamic switch

Tags: php, laravel, email, dynamic

I have situation that I have many subscribers from different countries. I have stored they language code and when I'm sending them email notifications I would like to switch to their language.

**How to switch language dynamically in `foreach` loop?**

```
foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){ 
        App::setLocale($subscriber->locale); ///!!!!!!!! HERE   
        $this->sendEmail($data);
    }
```

`App::setLocale()` not helping at all.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force locale in trans function in view as 4. param:

```
trans( string $id, array $parameters = array(), string $domain = 'messages', string $locale = null)
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and correct answer!! You saved my day :)